# VSS bindings are lost every time the solution is opened

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Every time I open a particular solution, the VSS bindings are lost and I have to rebind. Can anyone tell me why this happens and/or how to prevent it (short of never closing the solution, or having to do a "Get Latest Version")? This doesn't happen for every project/solution, only this one.

As always, thanks for the help.

P.S. I know the product sucks, but I have to use it.

Comment: which versions of VS and VSS?  how are you opening the sln? (from Explorer or VS?)  if you close the project and re-open right away, does it always happen?

Comment: VS 2005 and VSS 6.0. Yes, it happens if I close it and open it right away. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm opening the solution through VS.

Comment: I wish, but it's not my call. I just work here. There were rumors about moving to TFS, but nothing ever came of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's gonna be hard to find the root cause of the problem but it's probably related to corruption of binding informations stored in your folder.

One possible solution would be to delete the content of your project folder (you can try first by only removing VSS related files) and then re-open it from source control (in VS) to let VS recreate binding informations.

This will surely work if only you in your team are experimenting this problem... othewise... don't know.

If the problem still occure after that, I don't see other solution than re-installing your VS :-(

Hope that help !

Comment: I deleted the vss files from the solution and each of the 38 projects, then re-bound them. It's been a few days and so far, so good. I'll take this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

which version of VSS are you using?

In older versions of Visual SourceSafe (before 6.0c), after adding a solution of Visual Studio to its source control, the binding information was stored directly in the .sln and .proj files.

Since VSS 6.0c, all binding information is kept locally in files named MSSCCPRJ.SCC on the developer's machine.

after deciding where the binding info is stored, you can pinpoint the cause easier. before and after closing VS, open the .sln/ file with notebook and check whether it includes code similar to

GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
...
EndGlobalSection

Answer (score 0):

It may be because something might be intefering with the local copy of VSS solution on your machine. 
The local directory set for your solution contains two additional files besides your project files:
one is MSSCCPRJ.SCC and the other is TheSolutionName.VSSSCC.
In windows, their icons are in the form two arrows pointing in opposite directions.
I had accidentally deleted them (thinking they were junk) and then lost all bindings to the VSS solution. Please check if something similar is happening on your machine.

Another reason could be - using multiple versions of VSS on same machine.

Comment: I know what those files are and they were not deleted. There is only a single version of VSS on my machine, but thanks anyway.